# Is it safe to have missing class function declarations?

Tags: c++

I always wondered this (though the applications are limited at best).

I've got the following class:

```
//a.hpp
class A
{
public:
#ifdef FOO
    int foo();
#endif
};
```

A library (either static or shared) defines FOO, but an executable that links does not. Is this valid C++? What happens if foo is virtual? Is it the same across compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a violation of the One Definition Rule, and as such it is *undefined behavior*.  The fact is that because the function is non-virtual and the app cannot depend on it and... well, the *undefined* behavior will probably appear as *works*, but the program is not well-defined.

In a comment to Daniel's answer you state:

> If it is virtual, does it still get initalized in the vtable correctly, and just no one can take the pointer of A::foo?

If the function is virtual, then it is far more possible that the *undefined behavior* will be apparent in the code in different ways:

**If it is the only virtual function**

The memory footprint of the object as seen by the two parts of the program will differ, memory reserved and the use of that memory will be different.

**If it is not the only virtual function**

The memory footprint of the object will be the same, *but* the location of each function in the vtable will be different for the different parts of the program, which can cause calls to the wrong function and all sorts of issues.

Comment: This piece of code simulates the case of a virtual function: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/382973c61514d5b7

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor directives matter only to the **compiler**, not to the linking phase. Either FOO is defined or it is not, when the library is compiled. The compiled code is what it is, and if you link to it, you'll be able to use only the functions which existed when you compiled it.

Comment: Right, what I'm asking is that if foo was defined when it compiles, and I essentially circumvent the declaration of foo when I use the class, what happens? Does it just not look it up in the library? If it is virtual, does it still get initalized in the vtable correctly, and just no one can take the pointer of A::foo?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams You don't "essentially circumvent the declaration of foo when you use the class". That is a misunderstanding. When you use the class, you just use it, _as it was when it was compiled_.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The other two questions in your comment are a consequence of your misunderstanding. If you get that, the other two questions are no longer relevant. Either `A::foo` exists or it does not exist - there is no halfway. And whether it exists or not, it depends on whether FOO was defined when A was compiled.